# Why does the decrementing operator in PHP work in this way?

Tags: php, while-loop, operators, decrement

The following code:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$i = 5;
while($i >= 1){
    var_dump($i);
    var_dump($arr[--$i]);
}
```

has the following output:

```
int(5)
int(5)
int(4)
int(4)
int(3)
int(3)
int(2)
int(2)
int(1)
int(1)
```

but if we replace the two lines within the `while` loop with the single line:

```
var_dump($i == $arr[--$i]);
```

the code has the following output:

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

The first output shows that `$i` and `$arr[--$i]` are equal.

The second output shows that `$i` and `$arr[--$i]` are not equal.

Why this discrepancy? What am I missing?

Comment: You can boil it down to just `var_dump($i == --$i)`, which perhaps surprisingly is `true`.

Comment: @Álvaro I think OP is very aware of the index 4 = 5 thing and that's the expected outcome. The question is why the behaviour differs when combining the two expressions into one.